# Adding seconds to timestamp in python

Tags: python, timestamp, timedelta

I have tons of `timestamp` strings like this one `2017-04-18 05:03:40.966084` and the script needs to add seconds to the `timestamp`. I have been trying to turn the string into a legit `timestamp` object and then add seconds to it with `timedelta` but for some reason it isn't working.

This is what I have so far:

```
duration = "150.100"
timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
timestamp_e = timestamp+timedelta(seconds=duration)
```

Am I going at this the right way?

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error, is the result semantically wrong, or does something else happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `timedelta` is a good way to adjust a timestamp. However note that your `duration` variable is a string. As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) it should be an integer or float:

> All arguments are optional and default to 0. Arguments may be integers or floats, and may be positive or negative.